# How to receive the redis key expire evenst during the application died after the app recover?

Tags: redis, key

I have a problem.

Assume that my app is destoryed sometimes.And there were some key expire events during the destoryed time .After I recover my app ,how can I receive the events during the destoryed time?

please,thank you!

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem?

Comment: Thank you firstly.I want to receive the events that happened in my app destoryed time.

Comment: what type of events? and how your app will destroy?

Comment: the key of expire event. I use this type event to do something import about updating database.So I want to make my app can receive the expire events of all times even they happened during my app destoryed. The destoryed of my app means something unexpected such as killing it unrightly.

Comment: You add a key to redis with some time to expire and when expired you want to do something on your database? is this explanation true?if yes, you need to use task queue not redis. if explanation is not true, I did not understand your requirement

Comment: sorry for late reply. Yes ,your explanation is right.Did you mean message queue or others? Can you give me further hints? Thanks!

Comment: You need something like celery, I use celery in python. It will handle tasks for you. Any other question? I think it is better to edit your question now :)

Comment: okay,thanks,I wiil take a try.